# my code seems to ignore a loop for some reason

Tags: c#, for-loop

i'm trying to solve project euler's third problem but it seems that the compiler skips a for loop so it makes my code totally useless

note : the idea didn't show any syntax error

here's the code :

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const long n = 600851475143;
            List<long> factors = new List<long>();
            factors = getFactors(Math.Sqrt(n));
            long max = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<factors.Count ;i++)//this loop in particular , it doesn't print the "testing.."
            {
                Console.WriteLine("test....");
                if(isPrime(getFactors(factors[i])))
                {
                    max = factors[i];
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static List<long> getFactors(double number)
        {
            List<long> list = new List<long>();
            for(int i = 2;i<=number;i++)
            {
                if(number%i ==0)
                {
                    list.Add(i);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
        static bool isPrime(List<long> list)
        {
            if(list.Count == 2)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I run your code, I print out the length of the list just before the for loop. The printed value is `0`. Your list is empty, hence why the loop isn't executing.

Comment: You'll definitely want to look at how to use the debugger. It's an invaluable tool when trying to diagnose why your application is behaving different than you expect.

Comment: The reason for this is the square root of your chosen number results in a `double` with a decimal value. A non-round number modded with an integer is never going to equal zero.

Comment: @Abion47 - 'never' is exaggerated, but it will fail often. And modded is modulo-ed.

Comment: In addition to @itsme86's suggestion, here are some tips on [how to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) that you might find helpful.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: _"And modded is modulo-ed"_ -- if you're going to be pedantic (and I don't object to that), the `%` is not "modulo" at all. It's the _remainder_ operator, which is related to but importantly different from modulo arithmetic. As for _"'never' is exaggerated"_, I don't see how. A non-integer divided by an integer is always going to produce a non-zero remainder according to the rules of the `%` operator. For it to do otherwise would mean that for `x % y` there exists some integer `n` that multiplied by the integer operand `y`, produces the **non-integer** `x`.

Comment: I know but I still cal it modulo - that's the only way I use it. And `(2.0 % 2) == 0` prints `true` on my PC.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That's not a non-round number. That's a double with no decimal component. No `X.Y` double where `Y` is non-zero, when modded with an integer, will equal zero. Also as Peter Duniho pointed out, being pedantic about "modded" vs "modulo-ed" is sort of disingenuous when you are going to call it "modulo" even with the knowledge that it is the _remainder_ operator. I prefer "modded" because "modulo-ed" looks awkward and doesn't roll off the tongue.

Comment: Better work with integers only: change the method signature to `getFactors(int number)` and call it like `getFactors((int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(n)))`

Answer (score 1):

```
static List<long> getFactors(double number)
{
    List<long> list = new List<long>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++)
    {
       
        if (Math.Floor(number % i) == 0)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

number is a fraction, it will never == 0 unless its cast to an int

Comment: It is possible to pull the Math.Floor() out of the loop.